# How to specify a prefix to a service exposed with an ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want exposing various services with a single ingress.

```
rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      # The path is the URL prefix for the service, e.g. /api/* or just /*
      # Note that the service will receive the entire URL with the prefix
      - path: /service1/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /service2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 5000
```

The problem is the whole URL including the prefix is passed to the underlying services so all requests return 404 errors: `service1` and api don't respond on `/service1/some/path` but directly on `/some/path`

How can I specify a prefix to the underlying services?

**UPDATE**

I tried using rewrite-target as follows. Requests are sent to the `rasa-nlu` service, but they all trigger 404 because `rasa-nlu` still gets the `/nlu`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nlu
        backend:
          serviceName: rasa-nlu
          servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: remove the trailing slash and * and it should work. I have used this same pattern to map multiple APIs from different services and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

This might be what you are looking for;

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something
```

Note the **annotation** to rewrite-target.

Found this [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/rewrite)

Comment: I updated my question but your solution seems to apply to nginx ingress controller. Any idea of an alternative for standard Google Load Balancer?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. I work in Azure and we use nginx for our ingress. Doubtful, but is there anything you can do in a GLB to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This thread might be solved till now, but just for the sake of solution.
below will solve the issue, the default path will be /nlu when it is added to the re-write annotation. 
It is from the nginx re-write rule which gets applies to the definition of location directive.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /nlu
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nlu
        backend:
          serviceName: rasa-nlu
          servicePort: 5000
```